# How would I represent mathematical expressions in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to type the following sentence in the Eclipse editor 8.0 × 10 power 4 - But I am unable to get 4 represented properly, how should I do that?

Comment: Is this java?  8*Math.pow(10,4)

Comment: Where are you entering this expression?  More details on what you're trying to do - Eclipse does many things

Comment: via the editor on the java file

Comment: I was actually trying to type something like 8.0 * 10 power 4 in the editor, not sure how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your comment on a previous answer, it sounds like you're trying to write the expression like this:

> 8.0 x 10<sup>4</sup>

The 4 is in superscript - and unless the editor has support for putting text in super/subscript you can't do it without copying and pasting the unicode character representation for superscript 4. (Note, copying the 4 from this example will not give you a superscript 4.)

In HTML (which is how I wrote this here) you would use the `<sup>` tag.

Generally, when powers are written in plain text, the ^ symbol is used to denote that it is a power, like this:

> 8.0 x 10^4

Comment: Good answer. I now see what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 3):

8 * Math.pow(10, 4)

Comment: I don't think this works, the number 4 is still not positioned properly. I am trying to type the above text as a java comment